# Increasing the size of the star

Tags: symbols

I need to increase the size of the stars. How can I achieve that?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\let\savestar\star
\renewcommand\star{{\scalerel*{\bigstar}{\savestar}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 \{\star,...,\star\star\star\star\star\}.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

I am getting this:
[image]

I tried `\renewcommand\star{{\scalerel*{\savestar}{\bigstar}}}` and got this:
[image]

And I need this:
[image]

Comment: How about reverting the order: `\renewcommand\star{{\scalerel*{\savestar}{\bigstar}}}`?

Comment: It worked for the size but the shape changed. I have updated the OP

Comment: it is possible to do without of use `scalerel`. try `\let\savestar\star
\renewcommand\star{\bigstar}`

Comment: @Zarko The results are not the same, try `\let\savestar\star
\renewcommand\star{{\scalerel*{\savestar}{\bigstar}}}
\begin{align*}
 \{\star,...,\star\star\star\star\star\}.
\end{align*}
\renewcommand\star{\bigstar}
\begin{align*}
 \{\star,...,\star\star\star\star\star\}.
\end{align*}`.

Comment: To get the result of your desired screen shot, do not redefine anything, just use `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 \{\bigstar,...,\bigstar\bigstar\bigstar\bigstar\bigstar\}.
\end{align*}
\end{document}`. On the long run one usually regrets all these redefinitions, especially when one collaborates with others.

Comment: I’ll do that! Thank you very much!

Comment: @marmot, I know/ see this. My understanding of question is, that op like to replace `\star` with `bigstar`. However, I will not do this, Better is simple use `\bigstar` where is (really) needed.

Comment: @Zarko I wouldn't do that, I would just use `\bigstar` when I want a big star. (My interpretation is that there was a confusion about the order of the arguments, and it *is* confusing.)

Comment: @marmot, i just looked the images of desired result. If the problem is only redefinition and not final result, than I agree with you.

Comment: You can just use `\bigstar` instead of `\star`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it has solved by comments.